# Use environment variable to set compilation debug value in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I have a legacy ASP.NET WebForms application that's deployed in an Azure App Service.

I'd like to set the `debug` value of `<compilation debug="xxx">` using an environment variable. For example, the `debug` environment variable in the Azure App Service would get set to `true` (prod) and locally to `false` (dev).

The app is deployed to the App Service via a Git repository hosted on BitBucket.

I'm aware that the usual way of doing this is with two Web.config files (.release and .debug) and using transforms. But this app gets deployed when the code is pushed to a BitBucket repository, not through a build in Visual Studio.

Is there any way to do this with an environment variable, or even external file (e.g., similar to how appSettings can be pulled into a Web.config file using the `file` attribute)?

Answer (score 1):

- If the Debug attribute mode is set to true, debugging option is enabled. And if it is set to false, it disables the debugging option `locally`.
- I have set debug mode to `false` in my local `web.config` and tried to debug my application with breakpoint. I got the below alert.

[image]

***As Debug attribute is under `system.web` => `Compilation` tag , it won't come under the Configuration => `Application settings` / `Connection string` section of Environment Variables***

- AFAIK we cannot set the Compilation Debug mode in Azuer Environment Variables.

We have an option of `Remote Debugging` in `Configuration`  = > `General Settings` , which allows our Deployed Web App to debug Remotely.

[image]